How to reduce storage space in Git LFS
I am having problems with storing data in Git LFS. Previously I used LFS to manage large files in projects. But now the repository is full and I can't push anywhere.
Because I can't push to the repo, I also can't untrack the files being tracked in LFS. I thought I would duplicate a new repository, but when I git push --mirror it didn't work because I didn't have any empty data left.
I want to keep the commit history and I can't buy additional data packages. Is there any way to solve that problem?

Uploading LFS objects: 0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
batch response: This repository is over its data quota. Account
responsible for LFS bandwidth should purchase more data packs to tore
access.
error: failed to push some refs to
'https://github.com/NTNhaan/ScientificResearchProjects_KnightChessStatic.git'

When I check the files tracked in LFS there are a lot of .png and .dll files I tried stopping tracking those files but it didn't work and the files are still intact

git lfs ls-files fc31421d3c
* Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.1.0/Documentation~/images/AdvancedFeatures.png 4b79e95470
* Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.1.0/Lib/Editor/PlasticSCM/unityplastic.dll



Hi there, I suggest that is something to ask Github support :).
